# Setting one array equal to another array makes it behaving like an object, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have set:

> const [c, d ] = ["h", "i"]

in the browser console. It returns undefined.

After that, when I type **c** it returns **"h"**,
and when I type **d** it returns **"i"**.

To me it looks like an object where I have set the value of **c** and **d** according to  **["h", "i"]** 's order

I have been learning Javascript for the past 9 months. I am not sure what am I missing? Why it's behaving like this?

Comment: You're using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), you're not actually setting one array to another.

Comment: you can invent all the code writing you want, but do not expect that they can match the syntax rules of any language, even javascript

Comment: Why do you need to enter this into the console? ))

Comment: I was learning react hooks and I saw this in "useState" and when creating a new hook with the instructor. I was confused by this "const [state, setstate] = useState(false);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using destructuring - a great feature to directly get named access to nested properties of an Object or an Array:

```
const car= {
    color: 'blue',
    power: '120HP',
    brand: 'an awesome one'
};

// Object Destructuring
const { colorOfCar, powerOfCar, brandOfCar} = car;
```

You are then directly able to work with each of these variable names.
It is more or less short for:

```
const colorOfCar = car.color;
const powerOfCar = car.power;
const brandOfCar = car.brand;
```

Hoping it is helpful!

Update:
An Array can be destructured the following way:

```
const rgb = [255, 200, 0];

// Array Destructuring
const [red, green, blue] = rgb;
```

Short for:

```
const red = rgb[0];
const green= rgb[1];
const blue= rgb[2];
```

Comment: Does this works on Array too?

Comment: Yes it does!
I will update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are using destructuring assignment. Then variable c = arr[0], d = arr[1]

If you need to copy array:

```
const newArr = arr.concat();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set one array to equal another array all you need is:

```
const c = ["h", "i"];
const d = c;
```

Comment: Hi James, Thank you for your answer. Please advise what you did and why it's solving the question

Comment: Hi, I was just showing how to set one array to equal another (without making it behave as an object) as you mentioned in your question title.

Comment: Great. Please edit your answer with this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This statement

```
const [c, d ] = ["h", "i"]
```

is [destructuring](https://codeburst.io/es6-destructuring-the-complete-guide-7f842d08b98f), which is not an array assignment. It doesn't read as

> "an array having the elements c and d will be assigned the values of h
>   and i"

but it reads as

> "The array having the values of h and i are destructured into
>   variables called c and d, respectively."

Hence, the result is not an array, nor an object, but two variables. You can use babeljs.io to check the equivalent of your code:

```
"use strict";

var c = "h",
    d = "i";
```